# NullPointerException on a static attribute

Tags: java, arrays, filereader

I am creating a simple login program in java. Here is the code i have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PasswordProgram {

    public static String user;
    public String password;
    public static boolean part1Finish = false;
    public File file = new File("D:/file.txt");
    public FileWriter UsernameWrite;
    public char[] user1;

    public void part1() {
        System.out.println("Please create an account: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("Type in a username: ");
        String user = input.next();

        System.out.println("Type in a Password: ");
        String password = input.next();
        try {
            UsernameWrite = new FileWriter(file);
            UsernameWrite.write(user);
            UsernameWrite.write(password);
            System.out.println(user);
            UsernameWrite.close();
            part1Finish = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void part2() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );

        System.out.println("Please confirm your username: ");
        String usercheck = scan.next();
        int PassAttempts = 5;
        int UserAttempts = 5;
        user1 = user.toCharArray();
        user1 = password.toCharArray();
        char[] usernamecheck = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(user1, 0, user.length());
        System.out.println(usernamecheck);
        do {
            if (usercheck.equals(usernamecheck)) {
                while (PassAttempts > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Please confirm your password: ");
                    String passcheck = scan.next();
                    if (passcheck.equals(password)) {
                        System.out.println("Thank You ");
                    } else if (passcheck != password && PassAttempts > 0) {
                        PassAttempts--;
                        System.out.println("That is incorrect. Please Try Again");
                        passcheck = scan.nextLine();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("You have run out of Password Attempts");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else if (usercheck != user && UserAttempts > 0) {
                UserAttempts--;
                System.out.println("That is an incorrect username. Please Try Again");
                usercheck = scan.nextLine();
            } else {
                System.out.println("You have run out of Username Attempts");
                break;
            }
        } while (UserAttempts > 0);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PasswordProgram login = new PasswordProgram();
        login.part1();
        if (part1Finish == true) {
            login.part2();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem i am getting is in the method `part2`. Here when I try to add the username that was saved under the variable `user` into a character array to use it as a range I get the error `NullPointerException`.

After investigating i see that when running `part2` the value of `user` is `null` and therefore I get the error.

Is there a way I could do this through the `FileReader` method instead or how can i fix the current error I am getting ? Thank you.

Comment: on which line do you get the NPE ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the static field `user` is **never** assigned in `part1`, you get a `NullPointerException` when you try to use it in `part2`.

---

There are also other issues in the posted code:

- why there is a file involved is unclear
- you use `!=` with `String`, for example in `passcheck != password`
- you use equals between `String` and `char[]` in `usercheck.equals(usernamecheck)`
- `passcheck` is assagned but never used
- local variables (because of their names) are hiding some fields
- `UsernameWrite` and `UserAttempts` have non conventional names (should be  `usernameWrite` and `userAttempts`

Comment: the file stores the username and password which the user inpus

Answer (score 1):

You have two *user* variables declared, one which is static and has global scope, another which is local to part1().  When part2() is attempting to access *user*, it is using the static declaration, which is null.  Your modifications to *user* in part1() are done to the local variable.

This is something called variable shadowing and should be avoided at all costs.

See the below example:

```
class Ideone
{
    static String bla = "test1";

    public static void myMethod() {
        String bla = "test2";
        System.out.println(bla);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        myMethod();
        System.out.println(bla);
    }
}
```

It outputs:

```
test2
test1
```